# Python and Java MAC SHA256 encoding generating VERY SIMILAR KEY

Tags: java, python, base64, sha256, hmac

I'm creating a signed request (`SHA256` and `base64`) using `Java` and validating this request in `Python`. The keys that I generated are **really similar**:

Java:

```
UjuGTll3GF7H8MHWyJc41NAEcd-OZOeJLT9PiAevcsw
```

Python :

```
UjuGTll3GF7H8MHWyJc41NAEcd+OZOeJLT9PiAevcsw
```

The only diference happens with char `+` and char `-`. I cannot change the java code because I don't have access to it, I only know that it uses `javax.crypto.Mac`. However, my python code is:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
hmac.new(api_secret, url, hashlib.sha256).digest().encode('base64')
```

The variables `api_secret` and `url` have the same input in both languages (`Java` and `Python`)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`digest()` returns a string, so `encode` is just the [standard `encode` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode). According to the list of [standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings), specifying `base64` as the encoding means that [`base64.encodestring`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.encodestring) will be used. The alphabet used by that function includes `+` and `/`, which are the last two characters in the standard Base64 alphabet:

```
>>> base64.encodestring(chr(248))
'+A==\n'
```

If you want an encoded string that uses `-` and `_` instead of `+` and `/`, you need to use [`base64.urlsafe_b64encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html#base64.urlsafe_b64encode):

```
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64encode(chr(248))
'-A=='
```

So you'd need to do something like:

```
base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hmac.new(api_secret, url, hashlib.sha256).digest())
```

For this to work, though, you need to check that the Java code is also producing `_` instead of `/`, like `urlsafe_b64encode`.